# Tricky SAS transpose task

Tags: sas

I have a dataset in the following structure:

```
Application_ID  Product_ID  Product1_Category   Product2_Category
11111           a           m1                  m3
11111           b           n2                  n4
11111                       k3                  k5
11111                       t3                  t7
```

As you can see, there are two product_id in this application. Each product correspond to their product_category. As the product id come in sequence, the first product id will correspond to Product1_Category, and so on. Due to the weird data structure, I can't use the proc transpose procedure. Here is what the result should be:

```
Application_ID  Product_ID  Product_Category
11111           a           m1
11111           a           n2
11111           a           k3
11111           a           t3
11112           b           m3
11113           b           n4
11114           b           k5
11115           b           t7
```

I have tried to use proc transpose but the result is not what I want.

Comment: How do you know what Product ID should be, whats your rule? And what have you tried, per SO rules, you need to show what you've attempted so far and what you're having issues with.

Comment: @Reeza I have added more information in my post.

Comment: Why does your Application_ID incrementally increase for Product_ID b?

Comment: Your output doesn't seem to match your input.

Comment: Your dataset structure doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the first N rows have the values for the CATEGORY_ID variable?
If so then just use standard array method to transform but add in code to update the PRODUCT_ID from the appropriate one of the first N rows.

```
data have;
  input Application_ID $ Product_ID $ Product1_Category $ Product2_Category $;
datalines;
11111 a m1 m3
11111 b n2 n4
11111 . k3 k5
11111 . t3 t7
;

%let varlist=product1_Category product2_category ;
data want ;
  set have ;
  array p &varlist ;
  do i=1 to dim(p);
    if i <= nobs then set have(keep=product_id) point=i nobs=nobs;
    Product_Category=p(i);
    output;
  end;
  drop &varlist;
run;
proc print; run;
```

[image]